# Ruby on Rails Association with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am beginner Ruby on rails.Application have 4 model.State, Province, District and City.

**Model**

```
app/models/state.rb
Class State < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :provinces
end

app/models/province.rb
Class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :state
has_many :districts
end

app/models/district.rb
Class District < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :province
has_many :cities
end

app/models/city.rb
Class City < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :district
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140714165543) do

 create_table "states", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

 create_table "provinces", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "state_id"
 end

 add_index "provinces", ["state_id"], name: "index_provinces_on_state_id"

 create_table "districts", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "province_id"
 end

 add_index "districts", ["province_id"], name: "index_districts_on_province_id"

 create_table "citys", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "district_id"
 end

 add_index "citys", ["district_id"], name: "index_citys_on_district_id"



 end
```

I am using simple_form gem.I am Create CRUD for all models. My question is

When iam create some state. then i create provinces and assign to state *error* in browser . **state_id is nil**

```
    class ProvincesController < ApplicationController
    #GET /Provinces/new
    def new
    @province = Province.new
    end

    # GET /provinces/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /provinces
    # POST /provinces.json
    def create
    @province = Province.new(province_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @province.save
        format.html { redirect_to @province, notice: 'Province was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @province }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @province.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end
    end
```

_form.html.erb in province

```
   <%= simple_form_for(@province) do |f| %>
   <% if @province.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@province.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this province from    being saved:</h2>

   <ul>
   <% @province.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
     <li><%= message %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <% end %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.association :state %>

  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: For one thing, it doesn't seem like there is any method called province_params.

Comment: `def province_params`
      `params.require(:province).permit(:name)`
    `end`

Comment: Can you show us your `server log` generated when you `submit` the `form`?

Comment: <Province id: 7, name: "WestBank", created_at: "2014-07-14 18:53:28", updated_at: "2014-07-14 18:53:28", state_id: nil>

Comment: Try changing your `province_params` to `params.require(:province).permit(:name,:state_id)`

Comment: i post it, but my show.html.erb in province, `<%= @province.name %>
`, `<%= @ state.name %>` ,  error **NoMethodError in Province#show**

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: my show.html.erb in province, show error message, when iam add state name. <%= @state.name %>

Comment: I guess it should be `<= @province.state.name %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting **`state_id is nil`** because you haven't have it in the list of `permitted params`.

Change your `province_params` method to

```
def province_params  
  params.require(:province).permit(:name,:state_id)  
end
```

And with the error you are getting

> NoMethodError in Province#show

would be most probably due to this line `<%= @state.name %>` because `@state` is not defined in your `show method`.

It should be `<%= @province.state.name %>` as you are trying to display the `state name` of the `associated province`.

Comment: another question i have, i association update all details. Then i am in city show.html.erb, on this case how display city belongs to districts,province & state?

Comment: display city parent details districts,province & state

Comment: @MarySmith It is hard to guess what you want.The better way would be asking a new question clearly describing what you want.You will get help for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following generator to add the state_id field to the proviences table.

```
rails g migration add_state_id_to_proviences state_id:integer
```

then run the migration command

```
rake db:migrate
```